# Как получать id div по клику на него

Tags: javascript, html

не могу понять как правильно получать id div по клику на него. Написал вот такой вот код, вроде все работает хорошо, но когда заходишь на сайт с мобильного телефона. То id получается некоректно. Например нажимаешь на блок нечего не получил и так раза 3, потому получаю id, потом опять такая же ситуация. То есть click на мобильном устройстве не срабатывает с первого раза.

Эта система нужна когда пользователь нажимает на div менялась ссылка в попапе.

Есть ли еще какие то способы получать id div по клику ?

Буду рад вашей помощи.

```
<div id="buttonBlock">
<span id="lin1">1</span>
<span id="lin2">2</span>

<div id="testinnerhtml"></div>
</div>
```

```
      document.getElementById('buttonBlock').addEventListener('click', function(e){
      var id = e.target.id;
      document.getElementById('testinnerhtml').innerHTML = `
          <a href="<?php echo cl_link('link/${id}'); ?>" class="a-m-btn" data-spa="true">test link id
</a>
        `
    });
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить к отслеживанию события click также [touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchend_event). На чистом JS несколько событий можно добавить как показано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8796988/3129992).

Comment: Попробовал, все равно та же проблема. Особенно с первым div. Что бы получить его id нужно сначала получить id со второго или третьего div а уж потом только кликнуть на первый. По другому с первого div id не получается получить.

Запутанно но надеюсь понятно обяснил.

Comment: Нет, не понятно. Опубликуйте код, который отражает Вашу проблему. Разберитесь с чем конкретно у Вас проблема: с получением id элемента по клику/touch на нём, с логикой приложения, с обработчиками событий... В идеале создайте пример используемого кода воспользуясь для этого элементом "Фрагмент кода" (Ctrl + M) в редакторе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код рабочий. Тот адресс в ссылке что вы туда пихаете через `php` вызов работать не бутет. `JS` - отрадатываеться в браузере клиента, `php` - компилируеться на сервере.

```js
 document.getElementById('buttonBlock').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   let id = e.target.id;
   createElement(id);
 });

 function createElement(id) {
   document.getElementById('testinnerhtml').innerHTML = `<a href="link/${id}" class="a-m-btn" data-spa="true">test link id${id}</a>`
 }
```

```css
#buttonBlock {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.a-m-btn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonBlock">
  <span id="lin1">1</span>
  <span id="lin2">2</span>

  <div id="testinnerhtml"></div>
</div>
```